# Prove the probability is 0

Tags: probability, statistics

Let E and F be independent with E = AUB and F=AB. Prove that either P(AB)=0 or else P(not A and not B)=0.
I dont know how to solve it. Please help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the _definition_ of independent events? Can you figure out what $EF$ is in terms of $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $E,F$ are independent, you have $P(E) P(F) = P(E \cap F)$. Note that $E \cap F = F$.

Hence we have $P(E) P(F) = P(E)$, or $P(E)(1-P(F)) = 0$. This gives the required result.

Comment: I got that. Thank you very much.